# VBA - bad file name or number, run time error 52

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a pop up error in vba. I am a total beginner and cannot find a solution. I have checked similar cases from stackooverflow with a similar error, but it doesn't help. To the point. I have piece of code and I try to run a macro and get an error as in the title, and I'm sure the file and folder name is 100% correct, how do I change the code to fix the code?

```
Sub kom_transf()

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
dzis = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'  open file  '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'C:\Lic kom

Call create_folder

ChDir "C:\Lic kom"

Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:=Filt, _
        FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
         Title:="point the file which you want to use")

'   end if cancel
    If Filename = False Then
        MsgBox "Didn't choose any file"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Workbooks.Open (Filename)

'mark the data and copy by the user
Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range 
Select", Type:=8)
Application.Goto (UserRange)
Selection.Copy

'line where the error occurs is (below): 
'Workbooks.Open ("C:\Lic kom\templates\kom_template.xlsx")
'the error text: "run time error 1004  
'unable to find the file C:\Lic kom\templates\kom_template.xlsx
'is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

 Workbooks.Open ("C:\Lic kom\templates\kom_template.xlsx")
 Sheets("all_data").Select
 Cells(2, 1).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste`

'Piece of code where procedure create_folder exists:

'  check if folder exists if not create '

Private Sub create_folder()
Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
dzis = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")


If Len(Dir(Path & "\" & dzis & "_wgrywanie", vbDirectory)) = 0 
Then
   MkDir (Path & "\" & dzis & "_wgrywanie")
End If

If Len(Dir(Path & "\" & dzis & "_wgry\kom", vbDirectory)) = 0 
Then
   MkDir (Path & "\" & dzis & "_wgry\kom")
End If

If Len(Dir(Path & "\" & dzis & "_wgry\wier", vbDirectory)) = 0 
Then
   MkDir (Path & "\" & dzis & "_wgry\wier")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur and what's the text of the error?

Comment: Also include your `create_folder` procedure in the question please

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I've added the error text and which line error occurs. I am looking for create_folder procedure.

Comment: If you open file explorer and paste _C:\Lic kom\templates\kom_template.xlsx_ into the address bar does it open the file?

Comment: _I am looking for create_folder procedure._  Put your cursor in the word `create_folder` and press Shift+F2 - it will take you straight to the procedure.